# Footer in scrlttr2 gets cut by page end

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I'm writing an invoice in LaTeX with KOMA-Script and scrlttr2. But the payment information I have put in the footer is too close/gets cut off by the page bottom. The following example should look like this
[image: working example from the internet]

but instead looks like this
[image: my example]

the code I'm using is a copy and paste of the example but with everything removed:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\setkomavar{frombank}{Account number \\ Bank name\\
some other info}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{%
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{People1:}\\
John Doe\\
Jane Doe\\
Info-\#1 \\
Some Stuff
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{CEO:}\\
Jane Doe\\[1ex]
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{Court:}\\
Somewhere
\end{tabular}%
\ifkomavarempty{frombank}{}{%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\usekomavar*{frombank}:}\\
\usekomavar{frombank}
\end{tabular}%
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Recipient}
\opening{Dear Readers,}

\closing{Sincerely}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I am very grateful for any help.

Regards, haDe

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE. Thanks for providing the sample code for your problem. I would like to point out that you have skipped the `\documentclass` line and potentially other lines relevant to the layout of your letter in the beginning of the code. I suggest you add that to make the MWE complete, so others can help you more easily.

Comment: @MarkusG. Thanks. I've moved the `\documentclass`line to a separate line. I've deleted plenty of lines from the original example, but those were mostly related to setting komavars for addresses and such. I could link the PDF with the original code and preview, if that would help.

Comment: I think you must enlarge the reserved space: put e.g. `\csname@addtoplength\endcsname{firstfootvpos}{-1cm}` somewhere in your preamble. But there might be better ways, so only a comment and no answer from me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the position of the footer to account for the extra height.

```latex
\addtoplength{firstfootvpos}{-4\baselineskip}
```

The text area is automatically adjusted.